# Handle carriage return in the ELF file while load the data through SQLLDR in Oracle DB

Tags: plsql, sql-loader

Some times the ELF file which we received may contain carriage return or line feed char at the end of the segment/field. In this case, the data is staged properly since the data type of most of the stage table columns is VARCHAR2.

When move the data from stage table to transaction table, it is throwing data conversion error when the numeric or decimal value in the stage table holds carriage return or line feed char value.

Each segment in the file should end with the delimiter(|) but if delimiter not added at the end of the segment then we are facing the issue while move the data from stage to transaction table.

[image]

In the above data screen shot, 1st line will loaded properly but 2nd and 3rd (line's/) segment's last field value will be inserted in the table with carriage return char.

Below is the table definition:

```
OPTIONS (ROWS=1000, READSIZE=2097152, BINDSIZE=2097152, PARALLEL=TRUE)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'ELFFilePath'
APPEND

INTO TABLE STAGE_TABLE1
WHEN
FEED='FEED'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ELEMENT_NUMBER POSITION(1) DECIMAL EXTERNAL,
COLUMN1 CHAR(5),
COLUMN2 CHAR(11),
COLUMN3 CHAR(10),
)

INTO TABLE STAGE_TABLE2
WHEN
DOMAIN='DOMAINNAME'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ELEMENT_NUMBER POSITION(1) DECIMAL EXTERNAL,
COLUMN1 CHAR(5),
COLUMN2 CHAR(11),
COLUMN3 DECIMAL EXTERNAL,
COLUMN4 NUMBER
)

INTO TABLE STAGE_TABLE3
WHEN
DOMAIN='DOMAINNAME2'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ELEMENT_NUMBER POSITION(1) DECIMAL EXTERNAL,
COLUMN1 CHAR(5),
COLUMN2 CHAR(11),
COLUMN3 CHAR(30),
COLUMN4 CHAR(30),
COLUMN5 CHAR(50),
COLUMN6 CHAR(15)
)
```

**Please help me to handle carriage return/Line feed while load the data through SQLLDR**

Answer (score 0):

How about removing CRLF? Something like this presuming `COLUMN3` is the last column to be loaded; `chr(13)` is carriage return, `chr(10)` is line feed character:

```
INTO TABLE STAGE_TABLE1
WHEN
FEED='FEED'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ELEMENT_NUMBER POSITION(1) DECIMAL EXTERNAL,
COLUMN1 CHAR(5),
COLUMN2 CHAR(11),
COLUMN3 CHAR(10) "replace(:column3, chr(13) || chr(10), '')"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Loader assumes the file line ending based on the OS it's running on. You can override that; one way is to change

```
INFILE 'ELFFilePath'
```

to

```
INFILE 'ELFFilePath' "str '\r\n'"
```